# How can I correct "ssh: Could not resolve hostname nn.nn.nn.nn: Bad address" under git-bash?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, ip, git-bash

I'm running the latest version of git bash under Windows 8. Putty works correctly.

I can ping the following:
`sdf.org`
`192.94.73.15`

I can use `"ssh sdf.org"`
If I use `"ssh 192.94.73.15"` I get the error `"ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.94.73.15: Bad address"`

If I add a hosts file entry pointing to that IP it works correctly. It just appears that ssh is trying to resolve an IP address as a hostname.

This is affecting ALL ssh connections from this machine if using IP address. sdf.org is included in this description as it is public and available for anyone to test with.

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: This situation is weird and I've been pondering other explanations.. 
Does it work correctly if you use the `user@ip` syntax?

`ssh user@192.94.73.15`

Comment: no, same issue

`user@hostname` works, `user@ip` doesn't :(

Comment: weird, just plain weird. Hopefully someone has some insights. At this point all I can suggest is a bug report  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues